# Create a table, line-by-line of a dictionary using json.dump or pprint in django template [python]

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, django-templates

I've been banging my head on desk on this for a while, not sure if I should trying going at it some more, or see a Doctor.

I query an API for json information. I've been using requests, and the neat part of requests-tool i'm using is that you can call .json() and have it converted into a dictionary in python. Well, now here's the tricky part; I got all my data saved the way I want it, and now I'm trying to print all that json data back out on to HTML in a table format, or line-by-line essentially while keeping indentation that json.dumps applied, so then I could add some tags line-by-line. [see example below]

json.dumps() works beautifully at displaying it in pre-blocks, and now I'm stuck with how to have django template restructure that.

As i seen in most examples with json.dumps():

```
    {
        "a" :"string"
        "b" :"string2"
        "c" : [
            "yup",
            "yup",
            "blegh"
        ]
        "d" : {
            "another_dict": {
                "another_dict_to_make_it_tricky" : "string!"
            }
        }
    }
```

And what I'm looking for, or trying to do with a template, while preserving indentation.

```
    table
    row {
    row    "a" :"string"  (search-value-icon)
    row    "b" :"string2" (search-value-icon)
    row    "c" : [        (collapsible)
    row        "yup",
    row        "yup",
    row        "blegh"
    row    ]
    row    "d" : {        (collapsible)
    row        "another_dict": {               (collapsible)    
    row            "another_dict_to_make_it_tricky" : "string!" (search-value-icon)
    row        }
    row    }
    row }
```

So far what I've tried, is creating a filter jsondump to return the json string on the template, but when I'm trying to pass it to another filter, str_seperate it fails. And I've tried other ways but most of the indentation is lost when returning the information to the template.

*[Essentially; **{% dict_type_from_view |jsondump |str_split %}**]*

```
    @register.filter
    def jsondump(obj):
        return json.dumps(obj,indent=4)
    @register.filter
    def str_split(obj):
        return obj.split(',')
```

What's the most elegant way to do this preserving indentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the json.dumps() function you have to set the indent attribute. Also you have to split with '\n' as separator because Python would do some magic whitespace split otherwise. The last step is just rendering strings with leading whitespaces to some html.

You can try this:

```
import json
import re
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def my_filter(value):
    string = json.dumps(value, indent=4)
    result = '<div style="font-family:monospace;">'
    for row in string.split('\n'):
        content = re.sub(r'\s{4}', '<span style="padding-right:1em;">&nbsp;</span>', row.rstrip())
        result += '<p>%s</p>' % content
    result += '</div>'
    return result
```

In the template don't forget to use safe, but care that the content is really safe.

```
{{ my_dict|my_filter|safe }}
```

Comment: Hehe, oops, I have the indent added in there, I forgot to include that in my snippet. And as far as separation, I tried ',' but '\n' is something that escaped me.

Besides my errors, the filter you posted works great! For some reason, I didn't think to have a filter do all the work, instead of template side.  Thanks!